# ezdxf returning only a single path for a triangle hatch

Tags: python, svg, dxf, ezdxf

I'm trying to use EZDXF library to fetch the bounding path of a Hatch as a path made up of subpaths. I'll use this information to create an inline SVG on HTML.

[This is the shape I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D0IY.png)

[This is the image I'm expecting as seen in LibreCAD.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDZPE.png)

[I printed all the subpaths I'm getting for each Hatch path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngVxV.png) Evidently, it's just a single subpath for every hatch.

Code segment dealing with hatches:

```
        elif(i.dxftype() == 'HATCH'):
#           <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:0.2" /> 
            pathy = ezdxf.path.make_path(i) 
            firstSubPath = True
            fw.write("<path class=\"Hatches\" d=\"M")
            print("For a hatch")
            for j in pathy.sub_paths():
                print(j)
                if firstSubPath:
                    fw.write(str(j.start.x))
                    fw.write(" ")
                    fw.write(str(j.start.y))
                    fw.write(" L")
                    fw.write(str(j.end.x))
                    fw.write(" ")
                    fw.write(str(j.end.y))
                    fw.write(" ")
                else:
                    fw.write("L")
                    fw.write(str(j.start.x))
                    fw.write(" ")
                    fw.write(str(j.start.y))
                    fw.write(" ")
            fw.write("Z\" style=\"fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:0.2\" />\n")
```

Documentation says that path.make_path(Entity) returns:

> HATCH as [Multi-Path](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/path.html#term-Multi-Path) object

And for multipath object,

> the method [`Path.sub_paths()`](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/path.html#ezdxf.path.Path.sub_paths) yields all paths within this object as single-path objects.

Yet I'm getting a single subpath for every hatch. An example of a hatch path that I generated:

> <path class="Hatches" d="M3611.0489658828105 107.74118324488954 L3611.0489658828105 107.74118324488953 Z" style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:0.2" />

Apparently j.start and j.end have the same coordinates.

Is all of this an issue with the hatch in the dxf itself?

Comment: Okay, I made a rectangle hatch with the original rectangle and without it. Apparently Hatch object needs the outer rectangle to exit in order to create a path. Is there a way to fetch the boundary path without having a separately defined boundary path?